# Is a way to open app at fixed time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a radio application. The application have a option, like alarm. You set a hour and the application will become active.

Is a way to do this? Thanks

Comment: You can set LocalNotification for setting time and that fire notification at particular time but you must tap on notification banner or notification center window for open you app. App not going to be open automatically.

Comment: @NitinGohel Sachi vaat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You can play a sound at a specific time, even if your app is in the background, or you can send a notification (local or remote) to tell the user that he/she should open the app.

Comment: For play the sound i used a localNotification?

Comment: Yes. You can find the related information here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW31

Answer (score 1):

No. You could try creating a `UILocalNotification` which on action would activate your app.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to open application automatically on any specific time.